# Contact form 7 select dropdown submit download PDF

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following code in my theme file, but it doesnt seem to be working on submission of the form, I cant seem to work out why. Can anyone see the issue? :

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'redirect_page');

function redirect_page()
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
    if ('95' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
        console.log(event.detail.inputs['menu314']);
        var selectedValue = event.detail.inputs['menu314'];
        
        if (selectedValue == 'Download Guide for DFG teams') {
            window.location.href = 'url.pdf';
        } else if (selectedValue == 'Download Guide for Non-specialists') {
            window.location.href = 'url.pdf';
        } else if (selectedValue == 'Download Guide for Managers') {
            window.location.href = 'https://url.pdf';
        }
    }
}, false);
</script>
<?php
}
```

CF7 Form:

```
[contact-form-7 id="95" title="Subscribe download"]

<label class="uabb-cf7-col-1">[text* your-name placeholder "Name"]</label>
<label class="uabb-cf7-col-1">[tel tel-985 placeholder "Telephone"]</label>
<label class="uabb-cf7-col-1"> [email* your-email placeholder "Email"] </label>
[select* menu-312 id:menu314 "Select Guide" "Download Guide for DFG teams" "Download Guide for Non-specialists" "Download Guide for Managers"]
<label class="uabb-cf7-col-1">[submit "Download Guide"]</label>
```

console is showing no errors, form sends, but PDF is not redirected

Comment: Are you sure it's 95? What does the output in your console.log say?

Comment: Object
apiResponse
: 
contact_form_id
: 
95
into
: 
"#wpcf7-f95-o2"
invalid_fields
: 
[]
message
: 
"Thank you for your message. It has been sent."
posted_data_hash
: 
"7af980bb9c29518be291c328b01ce397"
status
: 
"mail_sent"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
contactFormId
: 
95
contactFormLocale
: 
"en"
containerPostId
: 
0
formData
: 
FormData {}
inputs
: 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
pluginVersion
: 
"5.5.6"
status
: 
"mail_sent"
unitTag
: 
"wpcf7-f95-o2"

Comment: Does the second console.log fire?

Comment: this seems to be all it does

Comment: can you put an additional else on the last condition, `else{window.location.href = 'https://google.com'}` and see if it redirects to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of input from the `event.detail` inputs is an object with the data in an array containing `name` and `value`.  The array keys have nothing to do with the names or id's of the fields, just an array.

Also, the contactFormId is an integer, for whatever that's worth.

So if you did.

```js
document.addEventListener(
    'wpcf7mailsent',
    function(event) {
        if ( 95 === event.detail.contactFormId ) {
            // 4th input field is key '3'.
            let selectedValue = event.detail.inputs[3]['value'];
            if ('Download Guide for DFG teams' === selectedValue) {
                window.location.href = 'url.pdf';
            } else if ('Download Guide for Non-specialists' === selectedValue) {
                window.location.href = 'url.pdf';
            } else if ('Download Guide for Managers' === selectedValue) {
                window.location.href = 'https://url.pdf';
            }
        }
    },
    false
);
```

where inputs[3] is the fourth field (which is your select), then you should get where you want to go.  If you `console.log(event.detail.inputs);` and expand the array to see the data, you should see the key if it's not `[3]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CF7 DOM events
[enter link description here](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

for example:

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  alert( "Fire!" );
}, false );
```